# How does psycopg2 server side cursor operate when itersize is less than data size and fetch number is less than itersize?

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, psycopg2, server-side

I have read the documentation and several articles and posts and threads and all but I am not sure if I understand this clearly. Lets suppose this scenario:

```
1. I have a server side cursor.
2. I set the itersize to 1000.
3. I execute a SELECT query which would normally return 10000 records.
4. I use fetchmany to fetch 100 records at a time.
```

My question is how is this done behind the scene? My understanding is that the query is executed, but 1000 of the records are read by the server side cursor. The cursor refrains from reading the next 1000 unless it scrolls past the last record of the currently read 1000. Furthermore, the server side cursor holds the 1000 in the server's memory and scrolls over them 100 at a time, sending them to the client. I'm also curious to know what would the ram consumption look like? By my understanding, if executing the full query takes 10000 kb of the memory, the server side cursor would consume only 1000 kb on the server because it reads only 1000 records at a time and the client side cursor would use 100 kb. Is my understanding correct?

**UPDATE**
Per the documents and the discussion we had in the responses, I would expect this code to print a list of 10 items at a time:

```py
from psycopg2 import connect, extras as psg_extras
    
with connect(host="db_url", port="db_port", dbname="db_name", user="db_user", password="db_password") as db_connection:
     with db_connection.cursor(name="data_operator", 
         cursor_factory=psg_extras.DictCursor) as db_cursor:
         db_cursor.itersize = 10
         db_cursor.execute("SELECT rec_pos FROM schm.test_data;")
         for i in db_cursor:
             print(i)
             print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
```

However, in each iteration it prints just one record. The only way I get 10 records is if I use fetchmany:

```py
from psycopg2 import connect, extras as psg_extras
    
with connect(host="db_url", port="db_port", dbname="db_name", user="db_user", password="db_password") as db_connection:
     with db_connection.cursor(name="data_operator", 
        cursor_factory=psg_extras.DictCursor) as db_cursor:
        db_cursor.execute("SELECT rec_pos FROM schm.test_data;")
         records = db_cursor.fetchmany(10)
         while len(records) > 0:
             print(i)
             print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
             records = db_cursor.fetchmany(10)
```

Based on these two code snippets, what I'm guessing is happening in the scenario mentioned before is that given the code bellow...

```py
from psycopg2 import connect, extras as psg_extras
    
with connect(host="db_url", port="db_port", dbname="db_name", user="db_user", password="db_password") as db_connection:
    with db_connection.cursor(name="data_operator", 
        cursor_factory=psg_extras.DictCursor) as db_cursor:
        db_cursor.itersize = 1000
        db_cursor.execute("SELECT rec_pos FROM schm.test_data;")
        records = db_cursor.fetchmany(100)
        while len(records) > 0:
            print(i)
            print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
            records = db_cursor.fetchmany(100)
```

... itersize is a server side thing. What it does is that when the query runs, it sets a limit to load only 1000 records from the database. But fetchmany is a client side thing. It gets 100 of the 1000 from the server. Each time fetchmany runs, the next 100 is fetched from the server. When all the 1000 on the server side are scrolled over, the next 1000 are fetched from the DB on the server side. But I'm rather confused because that does not seem to be what the docs imply. But then again... the code seems to imply that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would spend some time here [Server side cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors).

What you will find is that `itersize` only applies when you are iterating over a cursor:

```
for record in cur:
     print record
```

Since you are using `fetchmany(size=100)` you will only be working with 100 rows at a time. <s>The server will not be holding 1000 rows in memory.</s> **I was wrong sort of**. The cursor will return all the rows to the client in memory and then `fetchmany()` will pull the rows from there in the batch size specified if a named cursor is not used. If a named cursor is used then it will fetch from server in the batch size.

**UPDATE**. Show how `itersize` and `fetchmany()` work.

Using `itersize` and `fetchmany()` with named cursor:

```
cur = con.cursor(name='cp')
cur.itersize = 10
cur.execute("select * from cell_per")
for rs in cur:     
   print(rs) 
cur.close()

#Log
statement: DECLARE "cp" CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR select * from cell_per
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: CLOSE "cp"

cur = con.cursor(name='cp') 
cur.execute("select * from cell_per")
cur.fetchmany(size=10) 

#Log
statement: DECLARE "cp" CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR select * from cell_per
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
```

Using `fetchmany` with unnamed cursor:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from cell_per")
rs = cur.fetchmany(size=10)
len(rs)                                                                                                                                                                   
10

#Log
statement: select * from cell_per
```

So the named cursor fetches the rows(from server) in batches set by `itersize` when iterated over or by `size` when using `fetchmany(size=n)`.  Whereas a non-named cursor pulls all the rows into memory and then fetches   them from there according to `size` set in `fetchmany(size=n)`.

**Further Update**.

`itersize` only applies when you are iterating over the cursor object itself:

```
cur = con.cursor(name="cp")
cur.itersize = 10 
cur.execute("select * from cell_per")
for r in cur: 
    print(r) 
cur.close()

#Postgres log:
statement: DECLARE "cp" CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR select * from cell_per
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 10 FROM "cp"
statement: CLOSE "cp"
```

In above the `r` will be a single row that is fetched from each batch of 10 rows that the server side(named) cursor returns. That batch size is = `itersize`. So when you are iterating over the named cursor object itself all the rows the query specifies will be returned in the iterator, just in batches of `itersize`.

Not iterating over named cursor object. Using `fetchmany(size=n)`:

```
cur = con.cursor(name="cp") 
cur.itersize = 10
cur.execute("select * from cell_per") 
cur.fetchmany(size=20)
cur.fetchmany(size=20)
cur.close()

#Postgres log:
statement: DECLARE "cp" CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR select * from cell_per
statement: FETCH FORWARD 20 FROM "cp"
statement: FETCH FORWARD 20 FROM "cp"
CLOSE "cp"
```

The `itersize` was set but it has no effect as the named cursor object
is not being iterated over. Instead the `fetchmany(size=20)` is having the server side cursor send a batch of 20 records each time it is called.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually that page was the very first I read. But with what you pointed out, I'm understanding it differently now. So if that is the case, in some situations itersize and fetchmany will act similarly to a great extent. Which raises a new question. Where should fetchmany be used? Is it safe to assume fetchmany is used only when we are interested in getting a certain number of records and not when iterating?

Comment: See update to my answer. Turns out I was wrong. fetchmany operates differently when used in named vs unnamed cursor.

Comment: Thank you for the update. But I'm rather confused again. The code does not work that way or works in an unexpected way. I just ran your code on my own database and the only way I can get a batch of 10 is if I use fetchmany with the size of 10. I am using a named cursor. Based on the docs and what we discussed, I would expect the iteration variable `rs` to contain 10 rows when itersize is 10. But in each iteration it contains one row only. So, I'm confused again. What is an itersize of 10 referring to? Is my expectation wrong? Did I misunderstand again?

Comment: You will have to show your code(put it your question as it will be easier to see). The iteration is still going to take place one row at a time. What ```itersize```  does is set the size of the batch of rows it pulls from. So if ```itersize``` is  10 then the server cursor would return rows <= 10 and then the iterator would pull one row at a time from that batch. If there where more then 10 rows in the server cursor then the psycopg2 cursor/iterator would request another 10 rows and iterate over them one at a time.

Comment: I updated the question. So... my initial understanding was correct? Meaning `itersize` is a serve side limit which limits the number of records read from the database. While `fetchmany` is a client side limit which limits the number of records read from what the server has read from the database. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes and no. ```itersize``` works when a named cursor is iterated over. ```fetchmany()``` works when you fetching directly off the named cursor.

Comment: Ok, I know I'm pretty stupid and I should have understood it by now, but I want to be sure. So, given our discussion so far, if I create a named cursor with `itersize` of 1000, and I execute the query, the server loads the first 1000 records. If the client asks for the 1001st record, the server loads the next 1000. However, the records are all held on the server's side and sent to the client one by one, per iteration. While when I use the fetchmany method with size of 100, I am basically telling the server to send me the first 100, and then the next 100 and so on. Correct?

Comment: See my further examples.

Comment: Sorry for being absent for several days. So basically `itersize` and `fetchmany` have nothing to do with each other. Their only similarity is that they both select a batch from the full results of executing the query. While `fetchmany` takes a batch and sends it to the client side for iteration, `itersize` takes a batch and keeps it on the server's side and sends only one row to the client per iteration. Correct?

Comment: Correct on relationship of `itersize` and `fetchmay`. Almost there on `itersize` behavior.  It sends the batch of `itersize` to the client which then iterates over the batch.  So with a  batch size of 100, the server cursor sends 100 rows to the client which then iterates over those. If there are more rows in the server cursor then another batch of 100 is sent and so on. The purpose being to not send 1 row over at a time, which is default for non-named cursor, and to not send entire result set over at one time. You get to shape the result set size being held in memory.

Comment: Ok, now things are making more sense. Thank you very much! One last question. So, based one what we have discussed, if `itersize` and `fetchmay` have the same value, their difference in memory consumption should be completely negligible. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know for sure, you would have to monitor that to confirm.