# psycopg2 fetchmany vs named cursor

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, database-cursor

As per Psycopg2's [server-side-cursor documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors),

> If the dataset is too large to be practically handled on the client side, it is possible to create a server side cursor. Using this kind of cursor it is possible to transfer to the client only a controlled amount of data, so that a large dataset can be examined without keeping it entirely in memory.

I can achieve similar behaviour using [`fetchmany`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchmany):

```
fetchmany(100) # fetch first 100
fetchmany(50) # fetch next 50
fetchall() # fetch remaining
```

So, in the context of fetching controlled amount of data, how is `fetchmany` different from server-side-cursor? In what scenarios should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: See answer here [Server side cursor/fetchmany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623336/how-does-psycopg2-server-side-cursor-operate-when-itersize-is-less-than-data-siz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key is in the first paragraph of [server-side-cursors](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors) docs (my boldface):

> When a database query is executed, **the Psycopg cursor usually fetches all the records returned by the backend**, transferring them to the client process. If the query returned an huge amount of data, a proportionally large amount of memory will be allocted by the client.

With a "normal" cursor, the entire result set gets transferred to the client immediately. With a named cursor, you can "pull" data across the client/server interface as you need it.

For example, notice the difference in execution time of this program, depending on what type of cursor it uses (you may have to tweak the connection parameters):

```
import psycopg2, time
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='template1')
if False:
    c = conn.cursor('named')
else:
    c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(1,100000000)')
print('Execute ok.')
rows = c.fetchmany(1)
print('Fetch ok.')
```

Comment: No it doesn't. `fetchmany` fetches the user provided no. of rows from server. When it is called again, it fetches the next set of records. `fetchall` gets all the rows from the server.

Comment: @shiva, no, it works as this answers describes.  Without a named cursor, All the data is read into C structs in the python process's address space up front, by libc.  Fetchmany only controls the number translated into python structures at a given time, not how many are read from the server.

Comment: @jjanes You are right. I verified by tracking memory usage in both the cases.